# Email tracking with pixel in gmail's spam folder

Tags: gmail

In my project, I am using a 1*1 pixel which is used to track emails and it is working fine for all cases except in Gmail's spam folder. I tried to find the pixel in the console but in the spam folder, it was not there. After that, I am trasferred that email to my inbox, and the pixel was there again and the tracking was also working fine. Is this some kind of google proxy's doing?